# Return false if no DB row deleted?

Tags: php, mysql

I am somewhat new to PHP, but I am doing a course based on it at the moment.

I have a form where the user will input their email address in order to delete it from an email list.

I am trying to make an `if else` statement that when their email is not in the database it will error with "do not exist in the list".

As you can probably see the script does not work.

How can I see if the query succeeded and then return an appropriate message to the user?

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(censored)
            or die('error connecting to the database');
    $query = "DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die('Error Querying the database');

    if ($result == 0) {

        echo $email . ' do not exist in the list';
    }
    else {
        echo $email . ' is deleted form the list';
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: More information would help out here, what database software are you connecting to? (MySQL?), what PHP library are you using? (mysql, mysqli, PDO ?)

Comment: @Dale his tags are MySQL and MySQLi.

Comment: @Dale The code simply says "mysqli" (or maybe the code was added afterwards?)

Comment: What happens if you run the script as it is now?

Comment: @everyone the tags got changed after :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysqli_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysqli_affected_rows)

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect(censored)
        or die('error connecting to the database');
$query = "DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('Error Querying the database');

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) === 0) {

    echo $email . ' do not exist in the list';
}
else {
    echo $email . ' is deleted form the list';
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I think `===` should be `==` at line `if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) === 0) {`

Comment: I'm checking it's also an integer in this case but it could very well be a == yea :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<br/>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
</html>
```

Php Code

```
<?php
// on submit button 
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'databaseuser';
$dbpass = 'databasepassword';
$dbname = 'databasename';
//connection to mysql
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$conn)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//use database
$usedb = mysql_select_db($dbname , $conn);
if (!$usedb)
{
die ("could not select $dbname...<br/>");
}
//to delete record
$del="DELETE FROM tablename WHERE columnName = '$email'";
if(mysql_query($del))
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Record Deleted Successfully....!")</script>';
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}
}
?>
```

hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks!
altho I already had the form(as I wrote), and just wanted a solution on how to get true or false from the database. Thanks anyway :)